# Why would the struts submit button work in Chrome and firefox but not in I.E

Tags: jsp, struts, struts-1

I have this tag in my jsp:

`<html:submit property="command" value="Save"/>`

When I click on the button in other browsers my struts action is able to get a response. But in I.E8 this doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even I have the same problem with struts 1.3 tags like  etc..
Try to get the browser name through the HttpRequest properties and manage the things in your jsp page...